# Update cordova app without app store

Tags: ios, file, cordova, app-store

i need to update an cordova app via my own api. Is there any solution available?
I am thinking about a process like some games have - like "Clash of Clans" on start.

I've just thought about using file-api, but it seems like the directory is absolutely write-only and there is no way to execute my app from another place.

Sadly i can't use an simple app store update, as there is no internet connection on the devices. They just connect to an terminal provided with my software, in a closed environment.
So every third-party services are out :(

My thoughts is that i ship an app-update within my terminal software and the devices get that information an update themselves.

Any ideas?